# How to set configuration values in Sphinx theme or extension build event?

Tags: python-sphinx

I am building a Sphinx theme that sub-classes another theme, and sets several **default configuration values** in Sphinx (for example, a subset of values of `html_theme_options`).

I have tried writing a callback event function to read [`app.config`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#the-config-object) and set a variable if it does not exist, like this:

```py
def setup(app):
    app.config.html_theme_options["option"] = "value"
```

However, "value" does not seem to propagate to other stages in the Sphinx build process. If I inspect `app.config.html_theme_options`, I once again have the original default value before I reset it in my theme.

I have tried the same pattern in the `config-inited` and `builder-inited` [build events](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#events), but it doesn't seem to work in either case. Does anybody know how to over-ride Sphinx defaults via your own theme or extension?